# Recorded Excel macro with countIf function with lastrow

Tags: excel, macros, vba

My problem is following. I am recording macro for for sheet that´s range is dynamic.

The formula is `=CountIF(A:A;A2)` and recorded it:

```
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-12],RC[-12])"
Range("M2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M4333"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("M2:M4333").Select
```

Since the rows are dynamic, I want to end every formula to the lastrow. And I searched here for answer and copied this fuction to the beginning of the macro.

```
Function GetLastRow(sht As Worksheet, col As String) As Integer
GetLastRow = sht.Range(col & CStr(sht.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).row
```

Now I am trying to call this to the orginal recorded macro

```
Range("M2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Formula1 = "=COUNTIF(A:A" & GetLastRow(Sheets("Sheet1"), "A") & ",A2))"
```

I changed it looking like the formula that is copied in worksheet and not like it´s recorded. I would appreciate some help to this. It would be better if the lastrow function is used with recorded formula since I have lots other formulas to come with same problem.

Comment: It's [Range.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) or [Range.FormulaR1C1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx), not `.Formula1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to fill column M from row 2 down to the row in column M that meets the last populated cell in column A. Use the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) and [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) to get the correct address to use in the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34).

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")  'you should know what worksheet you are on!
    With .Range("M2:M" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(" & .Offset(0, -12).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ", RC1)"
    End With
End With
```

[image: AM_formular1c1]